# Import .sql to Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How could I import a .sql file to Oracle Database? It was exported using Oracle 11g, do I execute this script using SQL Developer or other tools?

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking, if the `.sql` file contains a sql script then just execute it with whatever tool that can connect to the DB - sqlplus, sql developer, plsql developer or something you've written by yourself

Comment: nope. actually the .sql was generated from an export. it contains database schema and some data.

Comment: @jeraldov Where do you want to execute your script? In sqlplus or some other tools like SQL Developer, Toad etc?

Comment: im not sure. i just need to execute that ".sql". i tried executing it in sql developer but returns errors like table doesnt exist. is it not the same as sql server where you just create a database and then import a .sql then it goes on smoothly?

Comment: @jeraldov Check your script whether it contains the create table syntax. If not check in your schema whether that table exists or not.

Comment: the drop statements goes first before the create table statements. i even tried commenting the drop statements and tried executing but still has error.

Comment: @jeraldov Could you edit your question and paste your syntax for create table? Or copy your create table syntax and try executing it in sqlplus or SQL Developer

Comment: You need to specify the exact error. Otherwise we are just guessing. Are you certain you are connecting to the correct database? what happens if you execute it line by line?

Comment: @jeraldov, it sounds as if the `drop table` commands failed because the tables weren't there - which is fine. After you commented these commands it failed because the tables are there and it's trying to recreate them without dropping them...

Comment: mm.. okay so lets say that if the export was done in a database named "EmployeesDB", should I create an EmployeesDB first and then run the script in that DB?

Comment: @jeraldov `EmployeesDB` means database or schema? If it is a schema then your sql scripts must be executed in `EmployeesDB`.

Comment: im not sure whats the difference between a database and a schema in oracle to be honest.